# Why doesn't IEnumerable<T>.Max constrain T to be IComparable?

Tags: c#, linq, generics

If one calls the `.Max()` extension method on an `IEnumerable<T>`, and the objects within do not implement `IComparable`, one gets `System.ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable.`

Why don't `Max` and similar methods constrain `T` to implement `IComparable`, so that this problem can be caught at compile time instead of at run time?

Comment: While writing the question I thought of an answer, but still thought it worth asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess because it's more flexible. For example, you may have an `IEnumerable<object>` which happens to contain strings, in which case `Max()` can be called quite safely on it, despite the fact that the type `Object` does not implement `IComparable`.

Comment: A difficult aspect of many design problems is deciding how to balance the pain of a robust system with a burdensome requirement against the pain of a flexible system that can fail at runtime. In this particular case, the designers opted for flexibility over robustness; whether that was the _right_ choice is certainly debatable, but some choice had to be made and neither option was perfect.

Comment: @Eric: +1, but I wish you had posted an answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 8):

Comparisons are... fun. Firstly, you've got a choice of `IComparable<T>` or `IComparable` - which would you choose? Currently (via `Comparer<T>.Default`) it supports both, but there is no "this **or** that" generic constraint.

Then you get the issue of `Nullable<T>`; this has "lifted" comparisons, so whether it is comparable or not depends on the `T`; but again, `Comparer<T>.Default` deals with this for us (`Nullable<T>` implements neither `IComparable` nor `IComparable<T>`).

Plus; it saves on generic constraint propagation; as soon as you have a constraint like this in library code, it quickly infects all the upstream calling code, making it a hard slog.

Comment: An insightful answer. Gets my +1 for now, won't accept yet as I don't want to discourage other answers.